# Return Userform Option button value to email body

Tags: excel, vba, email, radio-button, userform

I have a userform I want to give information to populate the body of an Outlook email.

I've been able to get the result with Comboboxes for Yes/No answers, but not for option buttons.

With the combobox yes/no dropdown I've been defining a variable based off the answer and then using it in the body of the Outlook email by referencing the variable with an &.

Option button sub:

```
Private Sub GetAnswer()
Dim OBAnswer As String
If OBYes.Value = True Then OBAnswer = "Yes"
ElseIf OBNo.Value = True Then OBAnswer = "No"
End If
End Sub
```

In my email sub, when I try:
`emailitem.Body = "The answer is " & OBAnswer`

I get a Compile error:

> Variable no defined.

I tried defining OBAnswer as a variant or using `OBAnswer.Text` in the email body code.

Comment: OBAnswer is only visible in the Sub since that is where it is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Sub to Function, and call that function to get your answer.

```
Private Function GetAnswer() as String
    
    If OBYes.Value = True Then GetAnswer = "Yes"
    ElseIf OBNo.Value = True Then GetAnswer = "No"
    End If

End Function

'// ...
emailitem.Body = "The answer is " & GetAnswer()
'// ...
```

Otherwise, if you need to store the answer ahead of time, just declare a public variable to hold the string outside of the `GetAnswer` method and reference that.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare the variable at the global scope to get access wherever you need:

```
Dim OBAnswer As String

Private Sub GetAnswer()

  If OBYes.Value = True Then 
    OBAnswer = "Yes"
  ElseIf OBNo.Value = True Then 
    OBAnswer = "No"
  End If

End Sub
```

Finally, you may find the [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) article helpful.